# Need to use specific rows based off of value Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am trying to get specific data from a panda dataset based off of the ID of the row.

This is an example of one of the checks

```
    if data_df.loc["rowID" == neededID]:
        df = data_df.set_index(['rowID']
        while i < df.rows:
            channel = client.get_channel(neededChannelID)
            message = newsChannelSender(df.iloc[i]) #this generates a message using the data send through 
            channel.send(message)
        i = 0
```

Since I'm using Pycharm, the error I get in the console is : **KeyError: 'False: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'**

I've tried being less and more specific within the if statement, but I get varying errors based off what I try.

For example I tried just comparing outside the set_index method, but that also didn't work:
`if data_df.loc["rowID"] == neededID:`

Comment: can you please try to make a minimal reproducible example and further explain what your goal is? are you trying to get a specific row from a df, or a specific value at a specific row/column?

Comment: Iam attempting to get just the rows with an id, then selecting each row with that id and generating a message with the contents of the row

Comment: thanks for explaining. can you make your question easier for us to answer by making a minimal reproducible example? for example `newsChannelSender` doesn't seem directly related to your question right? Is there a way for you to only include code that is relevant to your question? can you show us the first 5 rows of the data_df too? please don't screenshot